# File HttpPostedFileBase upload post NULL on partial view MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on multiple file post, I am using `HttpPostedFileBase`.

When submitting the form, the `file` property is `null`.

Model

```
public partial class Driver
{
    public int DriverId { get; set; }
    public string DriverFirstName { get; set; }
    ....
    public List<DriverImages> DriverImages { get; set; }
}

public class DriverImages
{
    public int DriverImageID { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }
}
```

Partial view

```
@model DataModel.DriverImages
...
@using (Design.Common.HtmlPrefixScopeExtensions.BeginCollectionItem(this.Html, "DriverImages"))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="file" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Controller

```
[httppost]
public ActionResult Create(Driver ObjDriverModel, HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
    // ObjDriverModel.DriverImages.file // always null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not generating a file input for your model property. It needs to be

```
<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.file, new { @type = "file" })
</td>
```

This will generate

```
<input type="file" name="DriverImages[xxx].file" .... />
```

where `xxx` is a `Guid`

and remove the `HttpPostedFileBase[] file` parameter from your method (note you would have received them have you renamed the parameter to `file` to match the property name, but then they would not have matched up to your model if any of the file inputs were empty).